# Existence of an element of a certain order in the center of a finite group.

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a group of order 2013 = 3·11·61. Prove that the center of G contains an element of order 11.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any ideas or thoughts you can share? Regards

Comment: Sean, welcome to MSE and I hope you have a productive time here discussing mathematics! I noticed that you haven't upvoted or accepted any answers to your questions yet. If you you like an answer (or if you think it's useful), then please upvote by clicking the arrow pointing upward to the left of the answer. If you think someone has answered your question and if you're satisfied, then please accept their answer by clicking the tick mark just below the pair of arrows (one pointing upward and one pointing downward) to the left of the answer. (E.g., I upvoted your question.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the number of Sylow $11$-subgroups, denoted $n_{11}$:

$$n_{11} | 3 \cdot 61 \implies n_{11} \in \{1, 3, 61, 3 \cdot 61\}$$

Further, $n_{11} = 11 k + 1$ for some $k$; thus, the only possibility is that $n_{11} = 1$, so $G$ has a normal Sylow $11$-subgroup $S$. Consider the centralizer $C := C_{G}(S) \leq N_{G}(S) = G$. We have that $G / C$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\text{Aut}(S)$, which has order $\varphi(11) = 10$. Thus,

$$|C| |G / C| = |G|$$

But $|G / C|$ is a divisor of $10$ and a divisor of $3 \cdot 11 \cdot 61$, so what can you conclude $|G / C|$ is? In particular, what does this imply about $|C|$?

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas:

**  Such a group has one unique Sylow $\,61-$ subgroup and one unique Sylow $\,11-$subgroup

** Thus, there exists a *normal* subgroup $\,N\lhd G\,$ with $\,|N|=671\;$

** From the above, $\,G\cong N\rtimes C_3\;,\;\;C_3=$ the cylic group of order three.

** Any automorphism of order $\;3\;$ must fix any element of order $\,11\,$ ...

Comment: +1 and a very nice solution as usual from you. Let me take this opportunity to let you know that I think your contributions to this site are excellent! I'm sure other users appreciate them very much too. It's great that we have a contributor of your calibre in a wide range of important mathematical subjects.